# find elements on basis of array of input Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Model is

```
  UserSchema = new Schema({
        email: String,    
        erp_user_id:String,    
        isActive: { type: Boolean, 'default': true },
        createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Now I have a list of string, which listt of [ erp_user_id], i want to search all users with  erp_user_id contains in this list.

something like

```
var inputArray = ['1234','324324','54345'];

User.find({inputArray.contains(erp_user_id)}).exec(function(err,users){
user;//  <---- list of users expected result
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputArray = ['1234','324324','54345'];

User.find({erp_user_id:{$in:inputArray}}).exec(function(err,users){
user;//  <---- list of users expected result
})
```

Comment: In your code the "list of users expected result" is `users` but not `user`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) Operator to Match Values in an Array.

The [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. To specify an [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) expression, use the following prototype:

```
db.collection.find({field: {$in: array}});
```

Your code:

```
var inputArray = ['1234', '324324', '54345'];

User
    .find({
        erp_user_id: {
            $in: inputArray
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(users);
    });
```